# lumen - how to access session variable in model?

Tags: laravel-5, lumen

Is there any way to get session variable in model ? My session driver is `session_driver=cookie` I have following codes in controller -

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
```

I am storing session variable like

`session(['current_session_id' => $session_id]);`
And in my model , I used

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;`

but it prints only `_token` , when I use

```
print_r(Session::all());
```

output

```
Array ( [_token] => mW5jx64fsAdkF3dOEis3F1Iqyz5Szu15eek0jMTr )
```

however in controller , it is printing

```
Array ( [_token] => UoG2PRXUzv7zIKj6WUTXkvM9WeLAe0tesCe3GSdx [current_session_id] => 7072345 )
```

Please help!!!

Comment: so your session token is different in between calls? are you using the model to early? what is session id? is it a special key that you are using? otherwise you can use `Session::getId();`

Comment: Why are you accessing the session in your model? That doesn't sound good. You should keep that separated, and only controllers and middleware should know about sessions.

Comment: @DavidNguyen , I couldn't understand 'model to early?'  session id is nothing but a time stamp string, it changes per page refresh.

Comment: @Alejandro , I want to store data in session array , where should I use it?

Comment: @SachinVairagi what kind of data? As I said, the model should not depend on sessions. I think the place to use it is the controller.